# SQL Server 2008 - Pivot on one column, group by another, maintain reference to third

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I've just started learning SQL and am struggling with transposing a three column table correctly.

Here's my starting point:

```
questionid | DebriefingQuestionResults | OperationSessionRecordID
------------------------------------------------------------------
32         |        3                  | 8071
34         |        0                  | 8071
36         |        1                  | 8071
32         |        2                  | 8074
34         |        6                  | 8074
36         |        5                  | 8074
```

And here's what I want to produce:

```
    OperationSessionRecordID | 32 | 34 | 36
----------------------------------------------
    8071                     | 3  | 0  | 1       
    8074                     | 2  | 6  | 5
```

There are only three [questionid] values (32, 34, and 36), but about 12000 [OperationSessionRecordID] values. All columns are of the type `int not null`.

I know I need to unpivot/pivot on [questionid] from my input table and group by [OperationSessionRecordID], but having looked at [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851588/pivot-rows-to-columns-with-more-than-1-value-returned) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632582/pivot-a-table-on-a-value-but-group-the-data-on-one-line-by-another?rq=1) I'm still very stuck.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851868/1842478) I've got this so far, but am not sure how to proceed as I'm working with a single table and therefore don't need the inner join.

```
SELECT [32], [34], [36]
FROM
(
    SELECT A.questionid, A.DebriefingQuestionResults
    , row_number() over(partition by a.OperationSessionRecordID)
    FROM dbo.TEMPtable AS A
) AS P
PIVOT
(
  min(P.Value)
  for P.questionid in ([32], [34], [36])
) AS PIV;
```

When I run this it throws this error, so something's obviously wrong with my use of row_number.

> Msg 4112, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause.

Any help would be most appreciated!

SB

Comment: Close the parenthesis after partition by.

Comment: @Mihai Ah yes good point! Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very straightforward pivot. Just:

```
SELECT OperationSessionRecordID, [32],[34],[38]
FROM TEMPtable
  PIVOT (
  min(DebriefingQuestionResults)
  for questionid in ([32], [34], [36])
) AS PIV;
```

You don't need to do anything special to get the grouping by `OperationSessionRecordID` - essentially, every column not mentioned in the `PIVOT` is a grouping column.

Comment: cheers, works exactly as I wanted. Thanks for explaining the PIVOT function too.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select 
    * 
From(
        select * From tbl
    )x pivot
    (
        min(DebriefingQuestionResults) for questionid in ([32],[34],[36])
    )piv
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Works perfectly. I've accepted the other answer as there's a bit more explanation as to what its doing and why it needs to be  in that format. SB :)