# SQL Server 2008 - Dynamic Pivot on one column, group by another, maintain reference to third

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've just started learning SQL and am struggling with dynamically transposing a three column table correctly. I [previously hard coded the query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240712/sql-server-2008-pivot-on-one-column-group-by-another-maintain-reference-to-t), but now need it to be dynamic as the values in my pivot column may change in the future.

Here's my starting point:

```
questionid | DebriefingQuestionResults | OperationSessionRecordID
------------------------------------------------------------------
32         |        3                  | 8071
34         |        0                  | 8071
36         |        1                  | 8071
32         |        2                  | 8074
34         |        6                  | 8074
36         |        5                  | 8074
```

And here's what I want to produce:

```
    OperationSessionRecordID | 32 | 34 | 36
----------------------------------------------
    8071                     | 3  | 0  | 1       
    8074                     | 2  | 6  | 5
```

There are only three [questionid] values (32, 34, and 36), at the moment but this may change in the future, hence wanting a dynamic query. There are about 12000 [OperationSessionRecordID] values. All columns are of the type `int not null`.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query) I've got this so far, but am not sure how to proceed as it throws the error shown below.

```
USE training_db
--Test to see if table exists, if so drop ready for creation--  
    IF OBJECT_ID('TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted
--Declare query and variable names--    
    DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get Distinct values of the PIVOT column--   
    SET @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.questionid)
    FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT OperationSessionRecordID, ' + @ColumnName + '
        (select questionid,
            DebriefingQuestionResults
            OperationSessionRecordID
            FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP)
            x
            PIVOT (
            min(DebriefingQuestionResults)
        for questionid in (' + @ColumnName + ')
        )
        AS PIV'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

When I run this it throws this error, so something's obviously wrong with my @ColumnName variable, but I can't work out what it is.

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   The multi-part identifier "c.questionid" could not be bound.

Any help would be most appreciated!

SB

Comment: So why don't you declare @DynamicPivotQuery variable?

Comment: @AK47 cheers, just spotted that! Updated to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
declare @collist nvarchar(max)
SET @collist = stuff((select distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(questionid) 
            FROM #t -- your table here
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

declare @q nvarchar(max)
set @q = '
select OperationSessionRecordID, ' + @collist + ' 
from (
    select OperationSessionRecordID, DebriefingQuestionResults, questionid
        from (
        select *
        from #t -- your table here
    ) as x
) as source
pivot (
    sum(DebriefingQuestionResults)
    for questionid in (' + @collist + ')
) as pvt
'

exec (@q)
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks very much @dean. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, I think you just misspelled variable name.

```
USE training_db
--Test to see if table exists, if so drop ready for creation--  
    IF OBJECT_ID('TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted
--Declare query and variable names--    
    DECLARE @    USE training_db
--Test to see if table exists, if so drop ready for creation--  
    IF OBJECT_ID('TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE TheatreMan.DebriefingQuestionsResultsPivoted
--Declare query and variable names--    
    DECLARE @QuestionPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get Distinct values of the PIVOT column--   
    SET @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.questionid)
    FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT OperationSessionRecordID, ' + @ColumnName + '
        (select questionid,
            DebriefingQuestionResults
            OperationSessionRecordID
            FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP
            ORDER BY OperationSessionRecordID ASC
        )x
        PIVOT 
        (
            min(DebriefingQuestionResults)
            for questionid in (' + @ColumnName + ')
        )
        AS PIV'

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
--Get Distinct values of the PIVOT column--   
    SET @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.questionid)
    FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP
    FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')
--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
    SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
    'SELECT OperationSessionRecordID, ' + @ColumnName + '
        (select questionid,
            DebriefingQuestionResults
            OperationSessionRecordID
            FROM dbo.DebriefingQuestionsResultsTEMP)
            x
            PIVOT (
            min(DebriefingQuestionResults)
        for questionid in (' + @ColumnName + ')
        )
        AS PIV'
    ORDER BY OperationSessionRecordID ASC
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out; updated and still not working. See question edit.